# maven installation setting up bash profile

Tags: maven, java-home

When I do a `mvn -version` I get the following error
FYI:- I saw the other related posts and none of it is resolving my prob

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/maven/cli/MavenCli : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:401)at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:254)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.getMainClass(Launcher.java:144)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:266)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

My bash profile is set as follows:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
export M2_HOME=/Users/ashvithavenkateshkumar/Downloads/apache-maven-3.3.9
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
```

Can someone please see what is going wrong here.

Also I am getting the error java home not found if the path is given as JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.6.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home
 but if I give as JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home then it works fine. (The difference is if i remove the _65  and jdk in front of the version)

Comment: Maven 3.3.9 requires Java 7...Starting with Maven 3.3.1 Java 7 is required. Furthermore M2_HOME is not needed and shouldn't be set. Just simply added the bin folder to the path and that's it.

Comment: May I also know what the PATH must point to as I am getting a browser errror.. I tried setting it to my firefox path which is under applications on mac but it says it is not binary

Comment: JAVA_HOME should point to <java_path>/jdk1.7.0_55  and PATH should point to <java_path>/jdk1.7.0_55/bin .  where jdk1.7.0_55 is the version of your Jdk